# Excel MEDIAN formula for values based on date

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I got stuck with a formula again if you can help :)

I need to find the MEDIAN for a range of dates that have a criteria, for example:

```
code   date    time

5X     08 Feb  5115

5P     08 Feb  5225

5P     09 Feb  5652

5X     09 Feb  5655

5X     10 Feb  5896
```

So, what's the MEDIAN for all the 5X values on the 09 Feb?
I figure it out with SUMIF and it works (A856 and A857 are the dates)

```
=SUMIFS($Q$2:$Q$132242,$B$2:$B$132242,"5X",$C$2:$C$132242, ">="&$A856,$C$2:$C$132242, "<="&$A857)
```

Is there a way to simulate a MEDIANIFS formula? 
Also, I can't enter dates manually because I have thousands of entries for years, it would take too long. I need to be able to just copy the formula.

Let me know if you can help. Thank you so much in advance.

**UPDATE (EDIT):**
This file is a mock-up of the problem: [Spreadsheet mock-up](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jusrYXj15e6ETXI87inS55JxtNec9ZYL/view?usp=sharing)
The formula needs to work on excel 2013 (so, no XLOOKUP). It also needs to be dynamic (no putting dates manually). The actual file has many dates in many years, so, I need to be able to select a median for any given date range. The median should be found for 5X and 5P. There's a target for 5X there to test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following array formula:

```
=MEDIAN(IF(($A$2:$A$11=A2)*($B$2:$B$11=B2),$C$2:$C$11,""))
```

Array formula after editing is confirmed by pressing `ctrl` + `shift` + `enter`

[image]

**Edit**

The formula has been supplemented in case the data contains empty values:

```
=MEDIAN(IF(($A$2:$A$11=A2)*($B$2:$B$11=B2)*ISNUMBER($C$2:$C$11),$C$2:$C$11))
```

Also array formula.

[image]

**Edit**

For the date period, the array formula must be supplemented with one condition:

```
=MEDIAN(IF(($A$1:$A$58=I57)*($B$1:$B$58>=J57)*($B$1:$B$58<=K57)*ISNUMBER($C$1:$C$58),$C$1:$C$58))
```

[image]

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for me. It results in a #NUM! error. Does this has a limitation on the numbers of entry? I have hundreds for each day.
I did ="5X" too without luck. It seems to work if I choose one criteria only, but not the dates.
I have other formulas working from the same data, so I know there's nothing massively wrong with the data itself.

Comment: Did you press `ctrl` + `shift` + `enter` to confirm the formula after edit?

Comment: Yes, if I didn't, it would have returned "0" instead. It has the brackets and everything on it, it is an array. 
I have a few cells that are empty, would that make a difference with your example? Can you remove a few values and see if it works for you? (on the time column only).

Comment: Yes, it works with empty values, with text values (ignore them). I can't even imagine what values the formula might not work with. Can you share problematic excel file in OneDrive or GoogleDisks and post link here? I will look at.

Comment: I can't share it, I'll try to think of a way to do a mock similar one. I had to do it manually for now, so I have the target values to keep trying. Also, I was wrong, it doesn't work with just one variable, it shows a number, but it is a wrong one. So, the only one that works is the SUMIF formula, the MEDIAN and IF is struggling to find the value and associate it with the correct one.

Comment: Yes, if there are empty cells, the formula treats them as zeros and the result is incorrect. I added a correction.

Comment: Just applying that fix still didn't work for me. It continues to result in #NUM! error :/ 
You might need to add 3 values in your 5X column so we can check that it is a median at work for the 8 Feb.
Such a tricky little F@%$mula. @basic

Comment: I added a spreadsheet with the target value for one of the ranges. I hope that makes it easier and you can help :) Thank you.

Comment: @MaxWill As you can see in last edit, the formula also works in your file and returns the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

*You can use this simple array (CSE) formula:*

[image]

- Formula in cell `C42`:

  ```
  {=MEDIAN(IF($A$36:$A$40="5X",IF($B$36:$B$40=DATE(2020,2,9),$C$36:$C$40)))}
  ```

Finish the formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**.

**N.B.**

*If you want to make the formula Dynamic then replace `5X` and `DATE(2020,02,09)` with cell references, and your formula should be like,*

```
{=MEDIAN(IF($A$36:$A$40=A$34,IF($B$36:$B$40=B$34,$C$36:$C$40)))}
```

*Where `A34` has **f**irst criteria `5X,` and `B34` has **s**econd one is date `02/09/2020`.*

*Adjust cell references & Date format as needed.*